# How can I use ESLint to refactor/restyle code in webstorm

Tags: webstorm, eslint

I added an ESLint file to my project and now I have like 1,000 "warnings" and red lines in my code. Is there a way to configure webstorm to use ESLint file to refactor my code using that lint file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way that I know of to get Webstorm to automatically fix the warnings just from your eslint configuration.
You could configure Webstorm's formatting rules to fix issues related to indentation, but that's be about it...

ESLint has recently introduced a way to automatically fix [some](http://eslint.org/blog/2015/09/eslint-v1.4.0-released/#autofixing-of-some-rules) [rules](http://eslint.org/blog/2015/09/eslint-v1.5.0-released/#autofixing-of-more-rules), but it's of course not exhaustive.